# ct_connect(): network packet layer: internal net library error: Net-Lib protocol driver call to connect two endpoints failed stackoverflow

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, sap-iq

While connecting to sybase, i'm trying to start my server using

> startserver

but, i have encountered the above error.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to start a Sybase instance is:

```
startserver -f RUN_SERVER_FILENAME
```

e.g  RUN_MY_INSTANCE or similar depending on what your Sybase instance is called. Once its started correctly then you should be able to connect. This is usually in the $SYBASE/$SYBASE_ASE/install directory on a default installation for Unix.

More info here:http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30191.1570100/doc/html/san1367605056632.html

Are you getting any other messages? You should look at the instance errorlog to check for problems on startup.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..! Yes, I have tried starting the server with the above command, but it is saying
`Cannot Open RUN_SYBASE`


At first the error was 

`Cannot execute RUN_SYBASE`
Then i have given the execute permissions and then tried, Now it is saying 
"Cannot open RUN_SYBASE"

Could you help....? 
and can you tell me the location of log files.

Comment: There should be a RUN% named file in the $SYBASE/$SYBASE_ASE/install directory. You also need to have a shell which has the correct $PATH, $LD_LIBRARY_PATH and other settings which Sybase requires so that could also be an issue. The default directory is $SYBASE/$SYBASE_ASE/install/server_name.log for the log but many sites change this from the default but try that location first.

Comment: The RUN% file is present and env variable is set and the log is 

`kernel  Job Scheduler Agent errorlog : /home/vadmin/sybase/ASE-16_0/install/SYBASE_JSAGENT.log
kernel  Job Scheduler Task state set to running, startcount 1.
00:0002:00000:00017:2019/03/29 02:43:57.95 kernel  Job Scheduler Task connected with Agent on port 4900
server  background task message: Account unlocked.
kernel  ueshutdown: exiting
kernel  Main thread performing final shutdown.
kernel  Blocking call queue shutdown.
kernel  SySAM: Checked in license for 2 ASE_CORE`

Comment: Can you confirm me that the problem is not related to **permissions** for the file/folder?

Comment: Normally your whole $SYBASE directory tree structure should be owned by the sybase user so should be permissioned sybase:sybase or similar so that's also worth checking via an ls -l or similar command.